# php adding 2 arrays into same session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

```
$firstarray = array(
  'name'=>$name,
  'address'=>$address
);

$_SESSION['info'] = $firstarray;

$secondarray = array(
  'postcode'=>$postcode,
  'email'=>$email
);

$_SESSION['info'] = $secondarray;
```

Hi guys, how do I add the array into session info without overwrite its value which are already inside? I want the session info contain the value of firstarray and second array all together.

Comment: create two dimensional array like `$_SESSION['info']['first']` and `$_SESSION['info']['second']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$_SESSION['info'] = array_merge($_SESSION['info'], $secondarray);
```